# Why does subplot_mosaic show an Error: 'Figure' object has no attribute 'subplot_mosaic'

Tags: python, matplotlib

I've a problem with "subplot_mosaic" because Spyder can't find it. Could it be because of the version?

The Code:

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.gridspec as gs

# Subplot_Mosaic

layout = [["logo", "text"],["bar", "bar"]]

fig = plt.figure(figsize = (5,5))

ax_dict = fig.subplot_mosaic(layout)

ax_dict["logo"].annotate(
    xy = (.5,.5),
    text = "logo",
    ha = "center",
    va = "center",
    size = 20
)

ax_dict["text"].annotate(
    xy = (.5,.5),
    text = "text",
    ha = "center",
    va = "center",
    size = 20
)

ax_dict["bar"].annotate(
    xy = (.5,.5),
    text = "bar",
    ha = "center",
    va = "center",
    size = 20
)
```

It is very strange because I have the right library. I also looked up here:
[Matplot Mosaic Subplot](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.subplot_mosaic.html#matplotlib.pyplot.subplot_mosaic)

The code should be right. It's also from a tutorial.

Does anyone see the problem?

Comment: What version of matplotlib do you have?

Comment: I've Version 3.1.0

Comment: Time to upgrade!

Comment: Now I have new problem :D, do u have tutorial to update packages in python?

Comment: Alright, now I have the version 3.6.1. Now it's working fine! Thanks :)!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Updating the version to: Maptlotlib 3.6.1 solved the problem!

Thanks to: @BigBen